# jquery.min.js - Google hosted - making automatic ajax requests

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery added via;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And when my page loads i get this;

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png. Origin http://demo.chrisdlangton.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The network shows the initiator is "jquery.min.js" !!!

Now correct me if i am wrong but does it not appear that google has its hosted jQuery library making XMLHttpRequest on behalf of thier users without consent or warning!?

EDIT: the below was posted as a comment BEFORE i was downvoted, making the down voter just as bad for not reading everything before passing judgement;
i have only a small piece of code, nothing in my css, js, html, php makes any reference to "favicon" let alone jshell or fiddle. By removing the jQuery link i no longer encounter this. Also, by using a jQuery script i had stored on my pc from an earlier date, version 1.8.2 also, i do not get this at all therefore its not in the jQuery i previously downloaded. When i save the google hosted .js and add to to my html locally i get this error. This morning when i still had the google hosted .js in my html there was no error By process of elimination its clear jQuery hosted by google caused this.

EDIT: this has stopped happening now - i have downloaded a copy of the .js that causes it and see it happening still when i use this downloaded copy but not when linking to the hosted .js. I'll be lodging a bug report with Google, maybe they were playing a trick.. wh knows.

Comment: See Same Origin policy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: i did not make the request, and i am well aware of CORS

Answer (score 0):

Any other scripts on your page? or plugins in your browser related to jsfiddle? Even though it says that jquery.min.js is the source, something could be (is) calling into the jQuery ajax function.

I wouldn't assume that Google's hosting is compromised, something is likely calling the ajax function.

Comment: i have only a small piece of code, nothing in my css, js, html, php makes any reference to "favicon" let alone jshell or fiddle.
By removing the jQuery link i no longer encounter this. 
Also, by using a jQuery script i had stored on my pc from an earlier date, version 1.8.2 also, i do not get this at all therefore its not in the jQuery i previously downloaded.
When i save the google hosted .js and add to to my html locally i get this error.
This morning when i still had the google hosted .js in my html there was no error

By process of elimination its clear jQuery hosted by google caused this.